# Using a shift() function within an apply function to compare rows in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I would like to use `shift()` to pull in data from the previous index, provided values in one of the columns, `Letter`, is the same.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'one'],
                        ['A', 'two'],
                        ['B', 'three'],
                        ['B', 'four'],
                        ['C', 'five']],
                  columns=['Letter', 'value'])

df['Previous Value'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['value'] if x['Letter'].shift(1) == x['Letter'] else "", axis=1)
print df
```

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'shift'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Desired Output:

```
  Letter  value Previous Value
0      A    one               
1      A    two            one
2      B  three               
3      B   four          three
4      C   five
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `where` on your condition where the current row matches previous row using `shift`:

```
In [11]:
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 'one'],
                        ['A', 'two'],
                        ['B', 'three'],
                        ['B', 'four'],
                        ['C', 'five']],
                  columns=['Letter', 'value'])
​
df['Previous Value'] = df['value'].shift().where(df['Letter'].shift() == df['Letter'], '')
df
​
Out[11]:
  Letter  value Previous Value
0      A    one               
1      A    two            one
2      B  three               
3      B   four          three
4      C   five
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to apply .shift() to a value of a given column of a given row instead of a Series. I would do this, using groupby:

```
In [6]: df['Previous letter'] = df.groupby('Letter').value.shift()

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
  Letter  value Previous letter
0      A    one             NaN
1      A    two             one
2      B  three             NaN
3      B   four           three
4      C   five             NaN
```